# Having to destinations to select for state design pattern

Tags: java, kotlin, design-patterns

I am implementing a state pattern, my cause when the pause state is reached,
I have two states that the user can back tow, that depends on the button the user click.

- if the user clicks on the Play button (start to selected)
- if the user clicks on the back button (died start selected)

Currently, the code

```
class PauseState : State {

    override fun handleClick(locationUIController: LocationUIController,
           deliveryType: DeliveryType){
     
            if(deliveryType == DeliveryType.PlayButton ){
         
            }
            if(deliveryType == DeliveryType.backButton ){
           
            }
     }
}
```

but I know there is something wrong
because switch statement breaks the benefits of state pattern that encapsulate behaviours , the code above shows ugly of switch statement

[states graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2Gfu.png)

Comment: Your question could be improved so people can help you. Given "you know something is wrong", can you explain what is wrong?

Comment: @ezaspi check it again

Answer (score 0):

ok ,
the problem is not with state pattern,
rather we still learning

Simply state pattern
any state becomes a class
any transition action becomes a method in the state if

```
interface LocationsCheckboxesState {
    fun pickupChecked()
    fun pickupUnChecked()
    fun dropOffChecked()
    fun dropOffUnChecked()
}
```